# Angular2 Deployment

Tags: apache2, virtualbox, angular2-routing

I have build an angular2 app and build it for production. I created .htaccess file as per angular deployment document. After placing the angular "dist" folder inside apache2 root directory I have no issue accessing any page of the project.

But Once I place the "dist" folder inside VirtualBox apache2 root directory and accessing it using the guest ip (VirtualBox) I am getting
'/ url not found on this server' for all the url except the '/' which is login[image: admin page].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

and aslo check  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dist">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After adding this and restarting apache, website runs fine.

Comment: Thank You So Much. You have help a lot. I was so worried. Also I add little on to your code:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>